# Unity3D insert string into array

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am using Unity3D 4.2 and have a button to trigger this:

```
function SubmitMove()
{
p1cube = new Array ();
p2cube = new Array ();
    var allCubeList = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cube");
    for(var allCube: GameObject in allCubeList) 
        {
        if(allCube.GetComponent(CubeARDP).cubeState == "1")
        {
        p1cube.Push(allCube.name);
        }
        else if(allCube.GetComponent(CubeARDP).cubeState == "2")
        {
        p2cube.Push(allCube.name);
        }
        }

}
```

So how the `p1cube.Push(allCube.name);` give me some error:

```
MissingMethodException: System.String[].Push
Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.MethodDispatcherFactory.ProduceExtensionDispatcher ()
Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.MethodDispatcherFactory.Create ()
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.DoCreateMethodDispatcher (System.Object target, System.Type targetType, System.String name, System.Object[] args)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.CreateMethodDispatcher (System.Object target, System.String name, System.Object[] args)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices+<Invoke>c__AnonStorey15.<>m__9 ()
Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.DispatcherCache.Get (Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.DispatcherKey key, Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.DispatcherFactory factory)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.GetDispatcher (System.Object target, System.String cacheKeyName, System.Type[] cacheKeyTypes, Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.DispatcherFactory factory)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.GetDispatcher (System.Object target, System.Object[] args, System.String cacheKeyName, Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.DispatcherFactory factory)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.Invoke (System.Object target, System.String name, System.Object[] args)
UnityScript.Lang.UnityRuntimeServices.Invoke (System.Object target, System.String name, System.Object[] args, System.Type scriptBaseType)
axisrotateDynamicParenting.SubmitMove () (at Assets/component_tested/axisrotateDynamicParenting.js:468)
axisrotateDynamicParenting.OnGUI () (at Assets/component_tested/axisrotateDynamicParenting.js:285)
```

Any idea what is going on?? I checked Unity script reference that whatever I do seems to be OK. Any help will be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `p1cube` is not a regular JS array there; somehow, you have a native .NET array.  Those aren't resizable, and thus don't have a `Push` method (because "pushing" by definition makes the array longer).

I'm parsing through the docs right now, so forgive my guessiness.  But it appears that if the array is declared as `String[]`, then it'll be a fixed-size, native .NET array.  In order to do what you want, you could either declare the two arrays as `Array`, or have your functions create their own local JS arrays that you turn into `String[]` once you're done adding stuff.

As for how/why you could smuggle an `Array` into a variable declared as `String[]`?  I haven't a clue.  But JS's type system is somewhere between "very dynamic" and "I just changed what `Object` means".  Maybe that's playing a part.

Comment: How can I add a JS Array specifically? I just `var p1cube : String[];` when declare the array.

Comment: @sooon: If i had to guess... `var p1cube : Array;`.  But i have literally never even seen Unity Script before, so that's just what it is -- a guess.  :P

Comment: I declare my array into this: `var p1cube = new Array(  [ ] );` and it works. I found the solution from [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/12785/is-there-a-way-to-define-arrays-and-objects-litera.html). Thanks for your insight @cHao, you save my day :)